# Is the $T$-annihilator of the sum of vectors the product of the $T$-annihilators of the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space and let  $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ be the T-annihilators of $\vec v_1, \vec v_2 \in V$ respectively (that is $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ are the unique monic polynomials of least degree such that $p_1(T)\vec v_1=\vec 0$ and $p_2(T)\vec v_2=\vec 0$)

Let $q(x)$ be the T-annihilator of $\vec v_1 + \vec v_2$. Is it true that if $p_1$ and  $p_2$ are relatively co-prime then $q(x)=p_1(x)p_2(x)$?

I think that it is true, unfortunately I was only able to prove that $q(x)|p_1(x)p_2(x)$ (that is $q$ divides $p_1p_2$):

$$(p_1p_2)(T)(\vec v_1 + \vec v_2)=p_1(T)(p_2(T)\vec v_1 + p_2(T)\vec v_2)=p_1(T)(p_2(T)\vec v_1)$$

but:

$$p_1(T)(p_2(T)\vec v_1)=p_2(T)(p_1(T)\vec v_1)=p_2(T)(\vec 0)=\vec 0$$

hence $$(p_1p_2)(T)(\vec v_1 + \vec v_2)=\vec 0$$

but the set of all polynomials $g(x)$ such that $g(T)(\vec v_1 + \vec v_2)=\vec 0$ is an ideal in the ring $F[x]$ hence $p_1p_2$ is multiple of $q$ (that is $q$ divides $p_1p_2$)

Then I only need to prove that $p_1p_2$ divides $q$ but this is where I´m having trouble.

I would really appreciate if you can help me :)

Comment: You're not assuming the minimal annihilator polynomials are relatively co-prime, so you might need to take their $\text{lcm}$ instead!

Comment: And if they were coprime? does the equality hold?

Comment: In that case, $\text{lcm}(p_1, p_2) = p_1p_2.$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)? The equality $p_1 p_2 = q$ (when $p_1$ and $p_2$ are coprime) seems to fall out of that theorem (applied to the $k[T]$-module $V$) without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s(v,0)$ be the T-annihilator of $v$. If $k\in \mathbb{F}[X]v_1 \cap \mathbb{F}[X]v_2 \Rightarrow s(k,0)|p_1$ and $ s(k,0)| p_2$. $\text{gcd}(p_1,p_2)=1$ implies that $s(k,0)$ must be $1$, thus $Ik=k=0$.

$p_1=\prod_{i_1} f^{l_{i_1}}_{i_1}$ and $p_2=\prod_{i_2} g^{l_{i_2}’}_{i_2}$,where these are irreducible factors. You have shown that $q= \prod_{i_1} f^{s_{i_1}}_{i_1} \prod_{i_2} g^{s_{i_2}’}_{i_2} $ where the $s$ and $s’$ powers must be less or equal to those in $p_1$ and $p_2$. Suppose by contradiction that at least one of these powers is strictly less.

Then, without loss of generality, $s_{i_k}<l_{i_k}$. Thus, $q(v_1)\not=0$ (if it were $0$, we would need $p_1|q$, which isn’t true). However, $q(v_1)=-q(v_2)\in  \mathbb{F}[X]v_1 \cap \mathbb{F}[X]v_2 \Rightarrow q(v_1)=0$. This contradiction establishes that in fact $q=p_1p_2$.